# Determining the final remainder.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

what is the best way to determine the remainder left after repeatedly dividing the quotients of that number by a fixed number?
for example:

```
n = 15;
i = 3;
q = 15/3 = 5;
q = 5/3  = 1 (quotients only)
q = 1/3  = 0;
therefore, remainer = 1%3 = 1;
```

here

```
 n = the number
 i = fixed number by which I want to divide
 q = quotient that I am getting everytime
 r = remainder left when finally quotient is zero
```

Since repeated division is one of the way to achieve this is there any other way to do this. (better way)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please state what you exactly want. And what you mean by "best way"?

Comment: by best way I mean the fastest way to calculate it. since this is the repeated division it takes a lot of time is there any other way to know the remainder which will be left when I go on dividing the quotient of that number which in this case is 15.

Comment: You're trying to get the most significant digit of the candidate number's base 3 representation, in your example. I think you probably have the best way already, in general. If it's part of a conversion process to get the whole representation in base 3 (or base $n$), you should collect the remainders as you go.

Comment: Exactly ! I want the most significant digit. But I was looking for some better methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficiently high precision real arithmetic, you can calculate it as follows.

First get $\log_in=\frac{\ln n}{\ln i}$. Then get its fractional part, $f=\log_in-\lfloor\log_in\rfloor$. Then $\left\lfloor i^f\right\rfloor$ is the most significant digit of $n$ in its base $i$ representation. (In base $i$ ‘scientific notation’ $n=\left\lfloor i^f\right\rfloor\times i^{\lfloor\log_in\rfloor}$.)